# How to retrieve SQLite database table values from bottom to top (last row to first row)

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, gridview, cursor

I am trying to retrieve elements of a sqlite table onto a grid in blackberry.
This is my code :

```
  Statement statement56 = db.createStatement("SELECT date,bill,rec,narration,id FROM Temp4");
  statement56.prepare();
  statement56.execute();

  Cursor c = statement56.getCursor();

  for (int i = 1; i < grid.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
      System.out.println("Inside first for loops");
      for (int j = 0; j < grid.getColumnCount() ; j++)
      {
          System.out.println("Inside second for loops");

          while(c.next()) 
          {

              System.out.println("Inside while"); 
              Row r;
              r = c.getRow();



              for (int k = 4; k >=0; k--)
              {
                  System.out.println("Inside for loops");
                  if(k==0 || k==3)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Retrieving date or narration");
                      grid.insert(new LabelField(r.getString(k)),i,j);
                  }  
                  else
                  {
                      System.out.println("Retrieving other values"); 
                      //  String p = r.getString(k)
                      String p = "" + r.getInteger(k);
                      grid.insert(new LabelField(p),i,j);
                  }                           
              } 

              // c.previous();
              //c--;
              System.out.println("Exiting while");                        
          }

          System.out.println("Exiting sec for");
          break;
      }
      System.out.println("Exiting first for");

      break;
   }

   statement56.close(); 
   db.close();
```

This is giving me the values of my sqlite table in bottom up manner.I want it exactly in the same manner as it has been inserted in the sqlite table.

i.e If my table contains

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
```

The output i am getting in the grid layout on blackberry is

```
u v w x y
p q r s t
k l m n o
f g h i j 
a b c d e
```

Anyone aware about the solution to this.Anticipating a reasonable help.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `ORDER BY` in your SQL query:

```
SELECT date,bill,rec,narration,id FROM Temp4 ORDER BY id DESC
```

You can use another sorting field instead of `id` if it's more appropriate.

If you don't have a field to sort, you can use pseudo field `ROWID`. This field can be used as auto increment field in any SQLite table:

```
SELECT date,bill,rec,narration,id FROM Temp4 ORDER BY ROWID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.But my table temp4 contains data that has been inserted in random manner.Also the id column is not unique in my case as it has been inserted from another table.So i am finding it tough to define one specific column to be used as ORDER BY.Is there any other way to retrieve values that have been inserted in random order for random fetch?

Comment: You should create another field (let's call it `number`), make it `AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and use it for sorting. Auto incrementing field is always useful, it will be better to have it anyway.

Comment: Yes i have used auto increment in my other tables.But this being a temporary table i havent used it.It either ways provide a numbering for the columns.

Comment: Try to use `ORDER BY ROWID DESC`. `ROWID` is pseudo column that can be used in any SQLite table. It's similar to auto increment field.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!That helped.I was trying to figure this out since hours.Thanks again.

Comment: Good. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Please don't put one question into another. Create separate question instead.

Comment: Sure.I have posted a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have rows like:

```
Id Name
1  Row1
2  Row2
3  Row3
```

Use ORDER BY CLAUSE can give you results like:

```
Id Name
3  Row3
2  Row2
1  Row1
```

In your case you can use below query:

```
SELECT date,bill,rec,narration,id FROM Temp4 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.But my table temp4 contains data that has been inserted in random manner.Also the id column is not unique in my case as it has been inserted from another table.So i am finding it tough to define one specific column to be used as ORDER BY.Is there any other way to retrieve values that have been inserted in random order for random fetch?

Comment: You can have a column like DateCreated & then you can use that column in ORDER BY CLAUSE.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a separate column "DateCreated" so you can use it in ORDER BY CLAUSE..